# backup/restore from database with using entity framework

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, c#-4.0, backup, restore

how to backup/restore from database with using entity framework ?

Is it possible with entity framework 4.0 ?

I am using the c#4.0 and wpf and EF4.0

Comment: Entity Framework is an **ORM** - object-relational mapper - designed to handle interactions with single entities and/or short lists of entities. It's neither designed for bulk operations, nor is it a server admin framework. So no - I don't think you can do this using Entity Framework - that's not its job.

Comment: Why would you do this using Entity Framework, i miss the reason. What do you want to backup and restore, which kind of database? And like marc_s explained, it's just an advanced ORM. Executing queries under the hood. It would be possible to backup and restore a database, but that will be alot of coding and the execute time will never be as fast as any other backup and restore.

Comment: Use an **appropriate** tool for the job! Either use SQL Server Management Studio to handle backup/restore - or if you **must** do it programmatically, use the **SMO (Server Management Objects)** which is intended for exactly these kinds of jobs .

Comment: How do I get backup/restore Without EF. What is the best way?

Comment: @marc_s : please Give me an example with SMO.

Comment: Is Google offline? OK - [here's a CodeProject article on the topic](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14848/Using-SMO-for-Backup-Restore-and-Security-Purposes) - and seriously: just Google for `SMO SQL Server backup` and you'll get **plenty of hits** to choose from....

Comment: I am from Iran. Google is filtered

Comment: [Here's another pretty good site with lots of SMO samples](http://www.sqldbatips.com/showarticle.asp?ID=37), and [this one focusses on backup and restore](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1849/backup-and-restore-sql-server-databases-programmatically-with-smo/)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have SQL Express, and thus no SQL Agent. Maybe that is the reason you want to export using Entity Framework? You can always do it with SQL

I just found a link which explains how you can do it, but until now it is just all based on the fact that i think you don't have an SQL Agent and you want to make backups.

http://www.winblogs.net/index.php/2009/11/22/automating-backup-of-databases-in-sql-20052008-express/

PS: This question has been asked before, in another way, take a look at the following answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/9184833/578552